# docker compose giving permission denied error on GCP

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose

I'm trying to run my docker compose file and I have a few issues

The first is I can not run `docker compose` I can only run `docker-compose` I'm running docker version 20.10.5. When I try and run `docker compose` I get an error saying docker compose not found. When I try and run my docker compose command using `docker-compose` I get the below error `docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up --build`

[image]

Comment: A PNG file isn't really enough to debug a problem.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: try to review this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/features-and-benefits)